# Put for loops inside a variable?

Tags: php, variables, for-loop

In all my years of writing PHP, I've never come across an occasion were I would need to put for loops inside a standard php variable.

**The reason:** I need to pass this variable through a JSON request.

See my current code below.

What I'm doing here is writing a script to generate a standard HTML table based on users requirements (e.g number of rows & columns). And I need to put all this HTML into a variable and pass the variable through a JSON request which then decodes and is displayed to the user.

Any advice/tips/tricks would be a huge help.

```
<?php
$trows = 5;
$tcolumns = 7;

echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr>";
for ($th = 0; $th < $tcolumns; $th++){echo '<th>[HEADER]</th>';
};
echo "</tr>";
echo "</thead>";
echo "<tbody>";
    for ($tr = 0; $tr < $trows; $tr++){ echo '<tr>'; 
        for ($td = 0; $td < $tcolumns; $td++){echo '<td>[CONTENT]</td>';
        };
        echo "</tr>";
    }
echo "</tbody>";
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Assign your output to a variable instad of echoing it directly?

Comment: @maxhb mind elaborating on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$trows = 5;
$tcolumns = 7;
$result = "";
$result .= "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
$result .= "<thead>";
$result .= "<tr>";
for ($th = 0; $th < $tcolumns; $th++){$result .=  '<th>[HEADER]</th>';
};
$result .=  "</tr>";
$result .=  "</thead>";
$result .=  "<tbody>";
    for ($tr = 0; $tr < $trows; $tr++){$result .=  '<tr>'; 
        for ($td = 0; $td < $tcolumns; $td++){$result .=  '<td>[CONTENT]</td>';
        };
        $result .=  "</tr>";
    }
$result .=  "</tbody>";
$result .=  "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Ah yes, this works like a charm. Thank you kind sir.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable, say `$output`, to store the html table in.
After you have finished building the table you can do whatever you choose with it. Print it out, use it in another variable to build a json object.

See below

```
$output = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered'>";
$output .= "<thead>";
$output .= "<tr>";

for ($th = 0; $th < $tcolumns; $th++){
    $output .= '<th>[HEADER]</th>';
};

$output .= "</tr>";
$output .= "</thead>";
$output .= "<tbody>";

for ($tr = 0; $tr < $trows; $tr++){

    $output .= '<tr>'; 

    for ($td = 0; $td < $tcolumns; $td++){
        $output .= '<td>[CONTENT]</td>';
    };

    $output .= "</tr>";
}

$output .= "</tbody>";
$output .= "</table>";

echo $output;
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. However Aju posted first, so I have to give him the green check. Thanks anyway friend.

Answer (score -1):

Use output buffering:

```
// Start output buffering
ob_start();

/*
  Your code here
*/

// Fetch buffered output and save to variable
$content = ob_get_contents();

// End output buffering, flush buffer. This outputs the buffer content
ob_end_clean();

// If you don't want the buffer to be output use this
// ob_end_clean();
```